# Code name one: Forms Commands

Tags: codenameone

I create 2 Forms In first one I create some Commands
I Want To get selected command and use it to re title second Form..

I try to use Command Action listener to Get selected command then I use String variable to handle Co

Answer (score 0):

If you use the GUI builder store a flag into a variable in the command event callback. Then in the forms "before show" callback just do:

```
if(flag) {
   f.setTitle("Other Title");
}
```

If you don't use the GUI builder just create a method called `showMyForm(String)` that accepts a title as an argument.